# How can i Validate Form Field in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I have a model named 'company' holding some properties like

- Name
- Address
- fax

And My View (of IEnumarable type (MVC# RAZOR)) has two forms one(form submitting data to different actions) to display list all the available company(existing). And another(form) i used to create new client with Name TextBox 
Like

```
@Html.TextBox("name","")
```

Here i want to add validation to that particular field. 
Suggest me the possible easiest way?? 
What i tried is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39016/Form-validation-with-ASP-NET-MVC(But it doesn't works)

Comment: It should work. Could you be more elaborate on your error. What error you get ?

Comment: refreshed page with no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my view has two forms

Therefore you need two view models because I suppose that the validation rules are different for those 2 forms. So you will have a `SearchCompanyViewModel` where the `Name` field will not be required and a `NewCompanyViewModel` where the `Name` field will be required.

Comment: Want to apply validation to 2nd form only

Comment: @Kannas, great, then you simply decorate your second view model properties with the necessary validation attributes.

Comment: I did it. I did all necessary stuff (suggested at mentioned link/ and few straight steps we generally follow) to apply validation. After doing all this, don't know what went wrong and my view returned back with no validation message

Comment: AAh at first Thanks Darin for your help.And secondly: i got success (i was returning RedirectToAction instead of View() ). Sometimes silly stuffs results in mess...newayz thankx